# Problem with SQL Server Merge Replication 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, merge-replication

[image]I have multiple replications: merge replications that sync the data on both Headoffice and Stores but from past two days I am getting these error messages and replication doesn't complete successfully for some store.
there are total 18  stores and 1 headoffice the data against each store is in syncronization with Headoffice.Attached is the ss of error message from replication monitor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.